# LaTeX doesn't work after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, latex

I just updated to Ubuntu 12.10 but now LaTeX doesn't work any more. Kile always asks me "did you run LaTeX?". I'm quite new in this stuff, so it seems a bit strange for me, because in 12.04 it worked always without any exception.
I also tried it with other Editors, but there were similar mistakes, so I guess it is related to the upgrade.
Perhaps anybody of you has a hint.

Comment: Have you tried running it through LaTeX instead (ie using the command line): `pdflatex /path/to/your/file.tex`?. This should help  to identify if the source of the problem is LaTeX or Kile.

Comment: I tried that and the answer was: " ***/.texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt doesn't match pdftex.pool
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied) "

Comment: @user1562373: And the answer for that is a [FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=formatstymy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2191/tex-live-error-on-ubuntu-10-04-pdflatex-fmt-doesnt-match-pdftex-pool) at StackExchange with a error similar to what you get.

The solution stated there was to remove the `~/.texmf-var` folder. Usually this folder only has "auto-generated" files, but try this:

```
mv ~/.textmf-var ~/textmf-var-mackup
```

and check if the problem goes away. If not, you can rename the backup folder to its original name.

Comment: Seems very much like a bug in Ubuntu to me. The default TeXLive does not create `~/.texmf-var`, but `~/.texlive$YEAR/.texmf-var`.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to the system upgrade: Precise and Quantal use different TexLive versions, so when Ubuntu was upgraded the old remaining files "confused" the new TexLive...

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading has a drawback - programs may not work because of different structures and/or different, new or redundant libraries.

**Solution :** Try re-installing Kile(or any other program not working).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I already tried that. The System-Check of Kile found out, that the LaTeX-Binary exists, but doesn't work. Does that give a hint?